# Bootstrap onhover for multi-level menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement multi-level bootstrap menu that is triggered by "hover". The first level works just fine. However for deeper levels the menu throws up everything as "visible". Need help customizing the CSS so that the hover works and makes only the required menu items visible.

```
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    right: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

My problem is illustrated in below fiddle. Thanks!

(Tried searching here for similar questions but couldn't find what I'm looking for)

http://jsfiddle.net/M7WHA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [immediate child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `>` like:

```
.dropdown-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/M7WHA/2/